# How to retrieve specific object from a getItem dynamoDB (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

getting an item from my aws database. 'test2' from below prints correctly as an item in my console. But I want to get a attribute/variable from it in the item, and return it as var test. How would I do that? For example if i wanted to get the attribute name 'problem' and return it?

```
var test;

ddb.getItem(param, function(err, data1) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
      var test2 = JSON.stringify(data1);

    console.log("Get Success",  test2);
    test = JSON.stringify(data1, undefined, 1);

  }
});
speechOutput = `Ok ${test}. Thanks, I have reported this. Do you have anything else to report?`;

    callback(sessionAttributes,
         buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
```

Comment: Really useful question.

Answer (score 8):

With aws-sdk you can turn an Item from a DynamoDB response into a more normal looking object using the Converter class available in the SDK:

So if `data1` looks like this:

```
const data1 = {
  Item: {
   "AlbumTitle": {
     S: "Songs About Life"
   }, 
   "Artist": {
     S: "Acme Band"
   }, 
   "SongTitle": {
     S: "Happy Day"
    }
  }
}
```

Pass `data1.Item` into the `unmarshall` function like so:

```
const flat = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(data1.Item);
```

And now `flat` will look like this:

```
{
  "AlbumTitle": "Songs About Life",
  "Artist": "Acme Band",
  "SongTitle": "Happy Day"
}
```

So you can access the properties like normal:

```
console.log(flat.Artist) #=> "Acme Band"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be just able to get the attribute with normal [property access in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), either `test.attributeName` or `test['attributeName']` where attributeName depends on what you want. In your example case, it would be `problem`.

But you should not do the `JSON.stringify` too early, since that'll convert the type to string and you cannot access the properties anymore (unless you parse the string back to object).